# file_postupdate_standard_editor function in Moodle

Tags: tinymce, moodle

code for editor in my **moodle form**

```
$mform->addElement('editor', 'title_editor', 'Questions', null, array('maxfiles' => EDITOR_UNLIMITED_FILES));
$mform->addRule('title', null, 'required', null, 'client');
$mform->setType('title', PARAM_RAW);
```

(form contain other fields too)

I submit the form and in action page I get the data as:

```
$data = $questionpool_form->get_data(true);
```

**$data** is:

```
object(stdClass)[127]
  public 'title' => 
    array (size=3)
      'text' => string '<p>What is the image shown below:</p>
<p><img src="http://localhost/moodle/draftfile.php/5/user/draft/717102051/111.png" width="297" height="203" /></p>' (length=153)
      'format' => string '1' (length=1)
      'itemid' => int 717102051
  public 'answer' => 
    array (size=2)
      'text' => string '<p>Brown color</p>' (length=18)
      'format' => string '1' (length=1)
  public 'blockid' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'courseid' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'submitbutton' => string 'Proceed' (length=7)
```

Since the image is in draftfile students cannot see the image. So to save and relink embedded images I use:

```
$definitionoptions = array('maxfiles' => EDITOR_UNLIMITED_FILES);
$data->id = null;
$data = file_postupdate_standard_editor($data, 'title', $definitionoptions, $context, 'block_question', 'title', $data->id);
```

And I print(check) the new data variable

```
object(stdClass)[127]
  public 'title' => 
    array (size=3)
      'text' => string '<p>What is the image shown below:</p>
<p><img src="http://localhost/moodle/draftfile.php/5/user/draft/717102051/111.png" width="297" height="203" /></p>' (length=153)
      'format' => string '1' (length=1)
      'itemid' => int 717102051
  public 'answer' => 
    array (size=2)
      'text' => string '<p>Brown color</p>' (length=18)
      'format' => string '1' (length=1)
  public 'blockid' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'courseid' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'submitbutton' => string 'Proceed' (length=7)
  public 'id' => null
  public 'editortrust' => int 0
  public 'editor' => null
  public 'editorformat' => null
```

But the image location is the same and that will not visible to student.

**My question is:**

What is the mistake in my `file_postupdate_standard_editor` function?

How can I save the image in correct location to display the images (if any) successfully?

**EDIT**

New `$data` variable after

> davosmith's

answer

```
object(stdClass)[117]
  public 'title_editor' => 
    array (size=3)
      'text' => string '<p>Find the color??</p>
<p><img src="http://localhost/moodle/draftfile.php/5/user/draft/239105225/flower_123.jpeg" width="200" height="200" alt="fff" /></p>' (length=157)
      'format' => string '1' (length=1)
      'itemid' => int 509796143
  public 'answer' => 
    array (size=2)
      'text' => string '<p>37</p>' (length=9)
      'format' => string '1' (length=1)
  public 'blockid' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'courseid' => string '' (length=0)
  public 'submitbutton' => string 'Proceed' (length=7)
  public 'titletrust' => int 0
  public 'title' => string '<p>Find the color??</p>
<p><img src="http://localhost/moodle/draftfile.php/5/user/draft/239105225/flower_123.jpeg" width="200" height="200" alt="fff" /></p>' (length=157)
  public 'titleformat' => string '1' (length=1)
```

**EDIT 2**

My moodle form contain the function **data_preprocessing**

```
function data_preprocessing(&$data) {
        if ($this->current->instance) {
            $courseid = required_param('id', PARAM_INT); // Do not use $_GET directly.
            $course = $DB->get_record('course', ['id' => $courseid], '*', MUST_EXIST); // Optional, but you often need the course object.
            $context = context_course::instance($courseid);
            $contextid = $context->id;
            $textfieldoptions = array('maxfiles' => EDITOR_UNLIMITED_FILES);
            $draftitemid = file_get_submitted_draft_itemid('title_editor');
            $data['title_editor']['format'] = $data['contentformat'];
           // $data = file_prepare_standard_editor($data, 'title', $textfieldoptions, $context,'block_questionpool', 'title', 0);
            $data['title_editor']['text']   = file_prepare_draft_area($draftitemid, $contextid, 'block_questionpool', 'title', 0, page_get_editor_options($contextid), $data['title']);
            $data['title_editor']['itemid'] = $draftitemid;

        }
        if (!empty($data['displayoptions'])) {
            $displayoptions = unserialize($data['displayoptions']);
            if (isset($displayoptions['printintro'])) {
                $data['printintro'] = $displayoptions['printintro'];
            }
            if (isset($displayoptions['printheading'])) {
                $data['printheading'] = $displayoptions['printheading'];
            }
            if (!empty($displayoptions['popupwidth'])) {
                $data['popupwidth'] = $displayoptions['popupwidth'];
            }
            if (!empty($displayoptions['popupheight'])) {
                $data['popupheight'] = $displayoptions['popupheight'];
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You've called your editor field 'title', then told file_postupdate_standard_editor to save the details of a field called 'editor'.

If you want to call the field in your database 'title' (and 'titleformat'), then the form field should be called 'title_editor' and the second param of file_postupdate_standard_editor (and file_prepare_standard_editor) should be 'title'.

You need to give Moodle the correct context, or it will not know where to save the files - if it is a block, then give it the block context or maybe the course context.

Comment: +1.Thank you davosmith for your quick replay. I changed the code. Now  the `title` and `title_editor` in `$data` variable have the same value(in both image is in the draftfile). Check my edited question.

Comment: I'd have to step through the code to figure it out, but I suspect that setting $data->id to null before using it in file_postupdate_stanard_editor will not help (set it to 0, if there is no appropriate value to set it to). At this point I'd strongly recommend putting a breakpoint on that function call, then step into the code to find out what is going wrong.

Comment: davosmith, please check my edit2 in my question. The form contain `data_preprocessing function` where I handle the `file_prepare_standard_editor`. I doubt is there  any issues.

Comment: `file_prepare_standard_editor` where and how can I call this function? `file_postupdate_standard_edito`r function I call in my action page.

Comment: file_prepare_standard_editor should be called before calling $form->set_data() (or could be called, in some cases, in the data_preprocessing function). Again, I encourage you to use xdebug and a breakpoint to step through the code and understand why file_postupdate_standard_editor is not doing what you want (or compare it with other usages in core code, which are working).